# Entitiy Framework How to improve to perfom on querying many relationship tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tables :
[[image: 1]]

Query Model :

```
...public string Keys { get; set; }
public int[] Cities { get; set; }
public int[] Sectors { get; set; }...
```

Controller:

```
public List<PostJob> SearchQuery(SearchFilterModel model)
    {
        var query = _postJobService.AsQueryable();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Keys))
        {
            var keyWords = model.Keys.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            query = query.Where(i => keyWords.Any(j => i.Title.Contains(j) || i.SeachTags.Contains(j)));
        }
        if (model.Cities.Length > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(i => i.JobLocations.Any(j => model.Cities.Contains(j.CityId)));
        }
        if (model.Sectors.Length > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(i => i.JobFeatures.Any(j => j.CategoryId == Startup.AppSettingsFeatures.Sector && model.Sectors.Contains(j.FeatureId)));
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

So it's recognizing the relationship between the two tables. I have many variable to filter and search to keys in info,search tags(maybe info).postjob table can be very big table in future so i need best aproach for search and filter query. I researched many documents and coded this code.

How to do improve my code for big tables?

what is best?

```
        query1 = query.Where(i => i.JobLocations.Any(j => model.Cities.Contains(j.CityId)));
        query2 = query.Where(i => model.Cities.Any(j => i.JobLocations.Select(k => k.CityId).Contains(j)));
```

what is best usefully search querying string array array in string (like  as search/contains keywords[] in Title,search tag,info)

Comment: This is far too broad. If the code works well today, then use it. One approach for optimizing a search query is to use a separate search index (SQL full-text, Elasticsearch, etc.) but you haven't provided enough detail to say.

Comment: @DanWilson each user can create many postjob -> post job have many locations -> postjob has 10 more features. i am thinking use elasticsearch in future but now i need best usefully ef search querying code

Comment: You can create a dynamic query based on datatype(int,varchar etc) bcz, in future many same datatype fields come.So, you will only need to create static logic for query based on datatype and fields name some dynamic when you do filters.

Comment: what best aproach ?
                query = query.Where(i => i.JobLocations.Any(j => model.Cities.Contains(j.CityId)));
                query = query.Where(i => model.Cities.Any(j => i.JobLocations.Select(k => k.CityId).Contains(j)));

Comment: what is best usefully search querying string array in string (like as search/contains keywords[] in Title,search tag,info)

Comment: @OMANSAK just as option - you always can create a stored procedure and use SQL Server tools for effective search.

Comment: @Max can you give me document or sample?