# MsSql FUNCTION and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using .NET CORE and Entity FrameWork . I am working on Search Querying in JobList that Query has keys,datetime,sectors,positions etc. filters.

My JobList table is setted Full Text Search and i need best approach for search querying.

I created a function for Full Text Search. This fucntion search keys in JobList and i need filter with relationship tables

[image]

```
ALTER FUNCTION F_SearchQuery ( @query nvarchar(3995),@offset integer,@next integer ) RETURNS @List TABLE(Id integer) AS 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @string nvarchar(4000)
        SET @string = '"'+@query +'*"'
        INSERT INTO @List(Id) SELECT FT_TBL.Id
                                FROM PostJob AS FT_TBL   
                                INNER JOIN  
                                CONTAINSTABLE (PostJob, (Title,SearchTags,Info),  @string) AS KEY_TBL  
                                ON FT_TBL.Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  
                                ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC  
                                OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @next ROWS ONLY

        RETURN
    END
```

My question is :

```
SELECT * FROM F_SearchQuery('software',0,10) 
INNER JOIN JobLocation J on J.JobId = JobId
INNER JOIN JobFeatures F on F.JobId = JobId
WHERE 
J.LocationId IN (filter locations) AND
J.FeatureId IN (filter features)
```

This query first execute and get table from F_SearchQuery() and after filter with where keywords ?

I need search query + filter relatioshios tables with sql function or Entity Framework IQuerable methods.

How is best way/approach for search querying ?

My other question : [Entitiy Framework How to improve to perfom on querying many relationship tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277146/entitiy-framework-how-to-improve-to-perfom-on-querying-many-relationship-tables)